# If positive number say yes if negative say no

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way that I can get the sum of 2 boxes when the formula goes through to present a yes or no in another box in the text of "Yes!" or "No!"

An example is if a1 = 4 and b1 = 5 I want c1 to run something like this:

```
c1 = sum(a1-b1<0 say no, a1-b1>0 say yes)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=IF((A1-B1)<=0,"No!","Yes")
```

Comment: Instead of `,` use `;`.

Comment: Indeed, you must use ; and not ,    That was the reason why my formula was wrong